# SSRS: Allow users to not enter a value at all in a multi value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a multi value parameter in a report I am writing to control which optional columns they can see.  I want to be able to let them choose to not show any optional columns by not entering anything.  However, I get a popup saying "Please select a value for the parameter".  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a check box for the parameter labeled 'Allow null values' - ensure that this is checked.

Alternatively, you can add a selection to the parameter's list of values such as 'No optional columns' and configure your report to use this value to hide the optional columns in an expression for the 'Hidden' properties of the columns.

Comment: You can't check that box if it is a multi valued parameter, SSRS won't let you.  I may have to go with your second notion.

Comment: That does have the advantage of letting you require them to make some choice, even if it is just to confirm that they don't want anything.